# Cant get cell value with changeType "OTHER"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the values of certain cells on an `OTHER` `changeType` using the Google Apps Script with spreadsheets. It works fine if the the `changeType` is `EDIT` or `FORMAT`, but not with `OTHER` which is the type I am after (sorting).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onChange(e) {

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A30:A32");
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();

    if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {

    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      var currentValue = range.getCell(i,1).getValue();

      ui.alert(currentValue);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple trigger "on change" (the function name onChange has no special meaning), so there should be an installable trigger set up for this function. In which case it works fine. I would recommend not using the deprecated Ui service, and not to fetch values one by one in a loop. My version:

```
function oc(e) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A30:A32");
  if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    var currentValues = range.getValues();       // get all values at once
    var str = currentValues.map(function (row) {
      return row[0];                             // flatten the double array
    }).join(', ');                               // join in comma-delimited string
    Browser.msgBox(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: I installed the trigger and just named the function `onChange`. I appreciate the effort and advice, but the exact same issue is present with your example. If the `changeType` is `OTHER` and triggered through sorting (`data > sort range`) - `getValues()` won't return the value

Comment: I tried this answer and it works for me.  Try deleting the trigger and creating a new one based on code above.

Comment: @utphx that's exactly what I did. I should specific, when I manually select a range and `sort range` - [you can see the behavior here](http://g.recordit.co/ux9SbObvMB.gif) -- you can see [what happens when I change `OTHER` to `FORMAT` here](http://g.recordit.co/plbeUk8yuE.gif)

Comment: @justinw It works fine in my spreadsheet, with the same kind of range sort as you did. What I see in your screenshot is that the trigger works but the data collection comes up empty.  Try putting `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @zaq it must be something with my sheet and the other functionality I have going on there. I should have done this before posting, but I just tested it on a. fresh sheet and your function works fine (so does my old crummy one), so I am not sure what is going on at this point. It was a bad move on my part not to check this before hand. I am going to accept your answer since it gives valuable information for improving my function. I appreciate the time and apologize for my lack of due diligence.